# How to stretch an image in one dimension?

Tags: imagemagick, bitmaps, image-processing

The title says much, but I'll explain in detail a little more.

I need to stretch an image in one dimension only. That is, if the image is for example, 100x100 (Width x Height) I need it to be 100x104 (Width x Height).

It would be perfect if it could be stretched by a certain percent (instead of putting in dimensions in pixels).

Anyone know how this could be done an in what? I tried looking in ImageMagick set of tools, but didn't find anything that I could use (not saying I didn't miss it in there though).

In any case, would appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Putting `!` after the geometry will do an anisotropic [resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize). Note that you may need to escape it due to the shell.

Comment: Seems like what I want. Could you be so kind as to give an example of usage?

Comment: From the link: `convert dragon.gif -resize 64x64\! exact_dragon.gif`

Comment: Nice job +1 for that!

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/). Gimp is the open source version of Photoshop. It is very easy to use. This tool will do everything you need and more...

Comment: But how does he resize in one dimension? ;-)

Comment: There is a tool in the Gimps tools menu to re-size an image. There is a link button that will make it not link together so that you can distort an image as you want.